# Ubuntu blank purple screen on startup

Tags: 14.04, boot, lightdm, startup, plymouth

I have Ubuntu 14.04 32bit LTS installed along with Windows 8 (dual boot).
I do not have any graphics card(nvidia ,amd ,etc). I have Intel hd graphics driver. It worked fine for many days, but now, on booting, GRUB boot screen works fine but when I choose Ubuntu (in grub menu) startup gets stuck with blank purple screen(with no splash screen).

On pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, Ubuntu splash screen (with white dots turning purple) shows for 2 seconds and then PC reboots.

I've tried to remove and reinstall lightdm (my default display manager)
from recovery mode but no success

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have a problem with grub rootdelay. After 20-30 sec try to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> write **exit** (you didn't see it on screen) and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. System should run OK. Then you need to 
[modify grub config](https://askubuntu.com/questions/522903/gave-up-waiting-for-root-device-alert-dev-disk-by-uuid-does-not-exist-drop).

But if it can't work try something else from [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it).