# Gave up waiting for root device. Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, system-installation, live-usb

I've been trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 from a USB drive for the last few days and running into the following issue on boot:

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
  — Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
    — Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
    — Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
  — Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! UUID=<drive-uuid> does not exist.   
Dropping to a shell! 

BusyBox v.1.20.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.20.2-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)   
Enter 'help' for list of built-in commands.  

(initramfs)
```

One thing to note from above: I can't use the shell (no response) after `(initramfs)` above in comparison to some solutions I've seen

For some context, I'm installing it on hard drive on a computer that has two other hard drives: one with a Windows 7 install and the other that's just NTFS storage. The Ubuntu installation is on `/dev/sdc1` and the boot loader the same.

Here are the things that I've tried to fix this, using a Live Ubuntu and chroot:

1. Validated that the UUID that appears after `blkid` is the same as that in `/etc/fstab`
2. Replaced the  path in `/etc/fstab` with `/dev/sdc1`. I get the same error of "Gave up waiting for root device" except the UUID is replaced with `/dev/sdc1`
3. After doing 2, uncommenting `GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true` in `/etc/default/grub`. Running update-grub afterwards.
4. Adding `rootdelay=40` and, separately, `rootwait` to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX in `/etc/default/grub`. Running update-grub afterwards.

I just don't understand how it's asying the device does not exist, since I have to go through the boot loader (on the same drive) to even start Ubuntu.

If it's an additional hint, when I try to run the Ubuntu recovery mode, it ends up looping on the line `Begin: Running /scripts/local=block ... done.` before giving me the original "Gave up" error.

There are [quite](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286284/system-no-longer-boots-gave-up-waiting-for-root-device-initramfs-dev-mappe) a [few](https://askubuntu.com/questions/522903/gave-up-waiting-for-root-device-alert-dev-disk-by-uuid-does-not-exist-drop) other posts about this, they've been helpful in debugging, but they don't seem to specifically apply to my situation:

Comment: grub should have been installed on /dev/sdc, not /dev/sdc1.   Are you sure there are no other grubs on other disks which are preferentially booting over the one on sdc?

Comment: Sorry -- to clarify, grub is on /dev/sdc and not /dev/sdc1. There are no other grub installations anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by burning the Ubuntu install ISO to a DVD and installing from that.

I still don't know what caused my original issue, but something about trying to install from a USB causes the issue above.

Comment: Something about *how* the USB was made is more like it.