# Need help with Ubuntu 16. Alert UUID does not exist. Dropping to shell. Happening inside the VM

Tags: 16.04, boot, grub2

[image: Screenshot of the error][image: GRUB info][image: UUID DESCRIPTION][image: GPARTED INFO][image: blkid info]

I have tried all the methods I could find on the Internet. Unfortunately, nothing fixed my problem. All these are happening inside a virtual box. Started happening after an audio update in Ubuntu. I can post the blkid and the UUID that creates the error if requested. I anyways dug the resume inside the conf file and it looks to be different.

I am not able to do sudo or edit the files inside Initramfs or the GRUB. Anybody who can help, please?
Update1 : The blkid and the uuid looks different. Any idea how to edit them?

Note: I am unable to copy paste the error message and hence I have attached the screenshot.

Comment: Please add an apt title of the problem and not the whole description of the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Gave Up waiting for root device. Alert! /dev/disk/by-uuid/ does not exist. Dropping to a shell" while booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/522903/gave-up-waiting-for-root-device-alert-dev-disk-by-uuid-does-not-exist-drop)

Comment: No, I tried that @Emmet. It does not look like it's on the VM.

Comment: @Tintin Changed.

Comment: @Emmet Unable to find even /boot/grub/grub.cfg inside my file list.